# Unable to install Xfce on Oracle Linux Server 9.1

Tags: xfce, gui, oracle-linux

I am unable to install Xfce on Oracle Linux Server 9.1.

I have a server built with the `Server`, `Container Management`, and `Headless Management` groups installed, and have connected to the EPEL repository.  `Xfce` appears as an Available Group.

When I try `sudo dnf group install -y Xfce`, it fails with the following error.

```
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/share/backgrounds/default.xml conflicts between attempted installs of desktop-backgrounds-compat-35.0.0-1.el9.noarch and oracle-backgrounds-90.2-1.0.2.el9.noarch
```

Is there any way to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the install after removing the offending Oracle backgrounds package.

```
 sudo dnf remove oracle-backgrounds-90.2-1.0.2.el9.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same on OracleLinux_9_1/WSL. The suggested solution doesn't work for me, because the backage oracle-backgrounds isn't installed, as
evidenced by

```
[jwi@C-B10108577 system32]$ sudo rpm -qa | grep oracle
oraclelinux-release-9.1-1.0.6.el9.x86_64
oraclelinux-release-el9-1.0-8.el9.x86_64
```

Comment: After my work, I discovered that Oracle has its own version of the EPEL repository.  Maybe that one would be compatible with Xfce in your system.

Comment: Thanks, Big Ed, but that repository doesn't contain the Xfce group, at all. Which is exactly, why I swutched to the standard one.